# d3 - problems with tickFormat + mutable variable accessible from closure?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an array of objects that maps actual tick values to what I want the display labels of the ticks to be. In other words, the object is keyed on tick value and gives the display value.

```
var tickMap = [{"27": 27, "28": 28, "29": 29, "30": 30, "31": "Test", "32": "Test2", "33": 33}, 
               {"50": 50, "58": "Test3", "66": 66, "74": 74, "82": 82, "90": 90}];
```

I then loop over this, and using the `tickFormat` property, try to return the display value for each tick value. `d` is the actual numeric value of the tick from `tickValue`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tickMap.length; i++) {
  index = i;
  dimensions[i] = {
    'tickFormat': function(d) {
      return tickMap[index][d];
    },
    // other dimension properties are here, including arrays of 
    // the actual tick values in the tickValues property.
  }
};
```

But this only ever seems to work for the second (or last) axis in the array. Instead of using `tickMap[i][d]`, I tried to declare `index` globally, and then assign the value of `i` to `index`, but that didn't help.

I also get the error "Mutable variable is accessible from closure".

I'm not sure how to fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that functions in JS maintain a reference to the actual variable that was created in their closure, not the value. This means that `i` in your code will be **the same `i` (same memory location) for every `tickFormat` function**, containing the value of `tickMap.length` which it got when the loop finished.

**ES6 Solution**

If you can use ES6, just use `let` instead of `var` and everything should work because `let` creates a new variable for each loop iteration, meaning each `tickFormat` function would get its own copy of `i`:

```
for (let i = 0; i < tickMap.length; i++) {
  dimensions[i] = {
    'tickFormat': function(d) {
      return tickMap[i][d];
    }
  }
};
```

**ES5 & bellow Solution**

Otherwise, you have to do the same manually by wrapping your loop code in an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) and passing `i` into it. This will create a new variable in IIFE's arguments which will, on each iteration, hold the value of `i` that was passed into the IIFE when it was created:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tickMap.length; i++) {
  dimensions[i] = (function iife(index) {
    return {
    'tickFormat': function(d) {
      return tickMap[index][d];
    };
  })(i); // <-- here you pass `i` as the `index`, maintaining a unique reference and thus the correct value for each `i`
};
```

Comment: You are the man! Thank you so much, this explanation helped tremendously.